# MEAN Stack how to catch errors correctly

Tags: express, mongoose, error-handling

I have written a function that is parsing the data returned from a url API with parameter date strings, which filters data based on some date range.

```
exports.list_FP_start_end_date_by_ID = function(req, res) {
    demo_id=req.params.demo_id;
    start = req.params.start;
    end = req.params.end;

    FP.findById(demo_id)
    .exec( function(err, fps) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {              
            startts = +new Date(start)
            endts = +new Date(end)
            TSarray = []

            for (let doc of fps["myColl"]) {
                ts = +new Date(doc["Timestamp"])
                if ((ts >= startts) && (ts <= endts)){
                    TSarray.push(doc)                                                   
                }               
            }
            res.json(TSarray);
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        res.json(err);
    })
};
```

The Request returns the corresponding subdocuments from the array. However, if I enter an ID as parametre, that does not exist, I get an error:
s.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'myColl' of null.

If I change the `".exec"` to `".then"` it catches the error correctly, however, I don't get returned the correct documents anymore, somehow, it messes up my query... how can I do best to catch / handle errors, or how should I fix my query instead?

Comment: Show these separate documents you get in results, as I don't see any reason why these should be different. Check the input paramters are actually the same as well.. The commented lines everywhere also make this difficult to read, so I would suggest you remove them.

Comment: ok I think this can be closed, my question was apparently answered on another place